# Нужна ли запятая перед «согласен»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*На переезд в другую местность(,) согласен.*

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не видно причины сомнений. Похоже на ДЗ.

Comment: Я думаю, что это обычная деловая расписка.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна:  ***На переезд в другую местность согласен.***

Это простое предложение, которое делится короткой произносительной паузой на две части:

*На переезд в другую местность // согласен.*

Но произносительная пауза не является грамматической, поэтому она запятой не обозначается.